# Weak reference getting zeroed out, but the object hasn't been deallocated

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

I have a `weak` instance variable holding onto a view controller in the `UINavigationController.viewControllers` stack.

My variable is automatically getting turned to `nil`, but the view controller hasn't been deallocated (since `UINavigationController` owns it).

Why is my weak reference getting zeroed?

```
class NavController: SuperNavigationController
{
    weak var weakViewController: UIViewController?

    required override init() {

        let rootViewController: UIViewController

        if (/* whatever */) {
            rootViewController = ViewController1(/*whatever*/)
            weakViewController = rootViewController
        } else {
            /* whatever */
        }

        /*** `weakViewController` is not `nil` at this point ***/

        /*** 
         *** This superclass function just does:
         ***   super.init(navBarClass:toolbarClass:)
         ***   viewControllers = [rootViewController]
         ***/
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    }

    // Without this, I get an "unimplemented initializer" exception
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

...
}
```

But as soon as I get to `viewDidLoad`, `weakViewController` is `nil`, even though `self.viewControllers.first` is still the exact same object I had when initializing.

Is there something weird about the way `UINavigationController` owns its `viewControllers`?

**EDIT:**
I managed to identify and fix the cause at a shallow level (see my answer below), but I'd still like to know why this happens.  I'll happily accept and upvote an answer which can explain what's going on!

Comment: You don't use `rootViewController` anywhere. It goes out of scope at the end of `init`. As a result, the weak reference isn't pointing to anything any more.

Comment: I actually do use it in the code this references; my real code subclasses another subclass of `UINavigationController`, and it has an `initWithRootViewController` function.  I'll update the code in the question.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `super.init()` was causing the `weak` subclass instance variables I had set to be zeroed out.

I fixed this by waiting to set `weakViewController` until after the call to `super.init()`

Answer (score 0):

A weak reference says that if nothing else is pointing at this, I don't need it. So if the owner is the only one who has a ref and that is weak, arc is free to deallocate it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: The actual object is retained by the `UINavigationController` because its `viewControllers` property is holding `rootViewController`, which is the same object referenced by `weakViewController`.  Since the actual object isn't getting deallocated, it doesn't make sense that `weakViewController` would zero itself.

Comment: The mechanic that is making your ```rootViewController``` go nil, is that ARC doesn't see any strong reference to it. Is it possible that you are passing this to the ```UINavigationController``` (or anywhere else in your chain of subclasses) by value? Is it possible that your ```NavController``` object is being destroyed before you are checking the ```rootViewController``` for nil?

Comment: Well `rootViewController` is a strong reference; `weakViewController` is the weak instance variable.  The navigation controller superclass sets the `UINavigationController.viewControllers` property before returning, so `rootViewController` won't have fallen out of scope.

Comment: As I stated in my answer, the `weakViewController` was zeroed out immediately after the call to super; I can't imagine how `self` could get destroyed while I'm still in the `init` function.